# show/hide sheets based on value in 2 cells

Tags: excel

Goodmorning,

in a workbook I have 6 sheets. First is visible at all times, the others are hidden.
Based on 2 cells, I like to have certain sheets visible.
I managed for 1 cell but not for 2 cells combined.

Options first cell (AU42) = "yes" or "no"; options second cell (L11): 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 or 6.
Both cells have a dropbox with above mentioned options.
Names of sheets: UT, UT1a, UT2, UT3, UT4 and UT5.

code I tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("AU42").Value = "yes" And Range("L11").Value = 3 Then
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = VeryHidden
End If
If Range("AU42").Value = "yes" And Range("L11").Value = 4 Then
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = VeryHidden
End If
If Range("AU42").Value = "yes" And Range("L11").Value = 5 Then
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT4").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT4").Visible = VeryHidden
End If
If Range("AU42").Value = "yes" And Range("L11").Value = 6 Then
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT4").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT5").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT4").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT5").Visible = VeryHidden
End If
If Range("AU42").Value = "no" And Range("L11").Value = 2 Then
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = VeryHidden
 End If
If Range("AU42").Value = "no" And Range("L11").Value = 3 Then
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = VeryHidden
End If
If Range("AU42").Value = "no" And Range("L11").Value = 4 Then
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT4").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT4").Visible = VeryHidden
End If
If Range("AU42").Value = "no" And Range("L11").Value = 5 Then
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT4").Visible = True
        Sheets("UT5").Visible = True
    Else
        Sheets("UT1a").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT2").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT3").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT4").Visible = VeryHidden
        Sheets("UT5").Visible = VeryHidden
End If
End Sub
```

tips or suggestions are highly appreciated, thks in advance.

regards,
Jonas

Comment: You need to add your code (that does it "for 1 cell"). Make sure to enclose between opening and closing ``` (so it's readable as code). That way, other can suggest what you might add or do differently (versus trying to guess what you're doing).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.